# How does google recognize my device when I login and have 2FA

Tags: google

I have 2FA turned on for my google account. I was using incognito to log in, and google still recognized my device;

[image]

I tried using a VPN to change my IP address, but it still recognized my device. I'm also pretty sure its not general device info like computer type or browser since that can easily be replicated using a VM. How else would google have done this?

Comment: Which device? Which OS? Which browser?

Comment: We need more info about your setup...

Comment: MacBook Pro, macOS Big Sur, Chrome

Comment: Chrome is definitely able to get information about your device and tie it to your account.  For instance they could poll the motherboard for hardware serial#s.  I believe Mac's also have a unique ID at the OS level which is tied to hardware.  This is a good thing™ as they can let you know when a new device logs in to your account.  If it bothers you, you can turn off the behavior in Chrome (and/or other browsers/apps you use...)

Comment: Btw, it doesn't need to poll your hardware at all.  Windows provides DPAPI which already provides similar security, and Mac has something similar... this ties to your OS' login (which ties to your hardware at some level).  You can remove trusted devices from your account if you like: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2544838?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop (It's all or nothing because they'll all be tied to one account...you revoke that token)  Sessions can always be stolen! (revoke if necessary)  Also, I think the checkbox you show doesn't indicate anything but a default selection.